# PHP using SQL addition of data from multiple colums together into another column

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<?php

  
    $sql = "SELECT Human, Total_Animals, Snakes, Lizards, Monkeys
    FROM Animals ORDER BY Total Animals DESC";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Human</th>
                <th>Snakes</th>
                <th>Lizards</th>
                <th>Monkeys</th>
                <th>Total Animals</th>
            </tr>";
        // output data of each row

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["Human"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["Snakes"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["Lizards"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["Monkeys"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["Total_Animals"]."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

So far this works in conjuction with my .css files and my html code. I am just trying to get the Snakes, Lizards and Monkeys columns in the same row to add up and the value be shown in another column.

So in table format it should be an output like

```
Human  |  Snakes  |  Lizards |  Monkeys  |   Total Animals   |

Fred   |    5     |    3     |     4     |        13         |
Mark   |    3     |    2     |     12    |        17         |
```

cant figure out how to do it for the life of me.

[image: Should look like this]

Ignore Name column, pretend it has names.

In the Total Animals column it needs to add the Snakes, Lizards and Monkeys column up and display it there.

Comment: Could you please explain the intended output a little bit better? Maybe an image?

Comment: Done, image is above

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT Human, Snakes, Lizards, Monkeys,
(Snakes + Lizards + Monkey) as Total_Animals
 FROM Animals ORDER BY Total_Animals DESC
```